Modify Windows CommandLine StartUp Text
I want to replace both text Powershell Startup and CMD StartUp below
# PowerShell
PS C:\Users\Admin>

# CMD
C:\Users\Admin>

with
PS >
CMD >

Like Python Start Up that only showing >>>
Is this possible?

For PowerShell, open the $profile file in your text editor and define a Prompt function.
Function Prompt {
    return "PS >"

    # color:
    # $esc = [char] 0x1B
    # return "$esc[34m" + "PS >" + "$esc[m"
}

Function Test-IsElevated {
    $me = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    $me = [Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] $me
    return $me.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator)
}

Function Prompt {
    if (Test-IsElevated) { return "PS # " } else { return "PS > " }
}

PowerShell uses PSReadline and I think it doesn't need anything special regarding color codes, but I'm probably wrong.
For Python, define the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable pointing at some path that becomes the startup script, then define sys.ps1 = in that file.
import sys

sys.ps1 = "PY >"
# color:
# sys.ps1 = "\x01\x1B[35m\x02" + "PY >" + "\x01\x1B[m\x02"

Python uses the same Readline as Bash does, but instead of the \[ \] that surround color codes, Readline expects \x01 \x02 instead.
For Cmd, define the PROMPT environment variable with the actual prompt string (see here or help prompt from within Cmd for the syntax).
While Cmd can have an autorun script, you don't need one for setting the prompt (it's enough to set the environment variable permanently, either using setx or through sysdm.cpl), so the following is just an example.
set PROMPT=CMD $G

:: color - if it works
:: set PROMPT=$E[36mCMD $G$E[m


set PROMPT=CMD $G works directly. I still search how to make it permanently

"either using setx or through Windows system settings" (I don't know where they've put the latter now, but it used to be under sysdm.cpl)

I make an Autorun REG_SZ in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor with value SET PROMPT=CMD $G. Done. CMD >.  Thanks for Your help, Bro.

I ask about Python. Perhaps you will answer it. https://superuser.com/questions/1840561/how-to-make-python-loads-scripts-automatically-when-python-runs
