How to Make Python CommandLine Loads Script Automatically When Opened?
Is possible a script to automatically loaded when python (Interactive Mode) is executed?
I mean like the script in $Profile PowerShell, which when PowerShell executed, the script is automatically loaded.
Python script example:
# autorun.py
import os
def cls():
    os.system("CLS")
def pause():
    os.system("pause")
    #input("Press Enter to continue...")
    

How to make the script automatically loaded when python starts?
When I call Python with command py or Python.

Yes, but there is no default path for a startup script – you have to manually set the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable first, pointing to the script you want to be run.
C:\>  set PYTHONSTARTUP=%APPDATA%\pythonrc.py
C:\>  setx PYTHONSTARTUP "%PYTHONSTARTUP%"

It will only be loaded when starting interactive sessions – not when running a .py script. Scripts need to explicitly import the modules they want.
(To make it easier for scripts, you can either place the custom module files in the same directory alongside the script files, or you can set PYTHONPATH to a directory that contains the custom modules – either way, you would then put all the convenience functions in something like "mylib.py" and be able to from mylib import cls, pause, etc, etc.)

I will ask for non-interactive mode as new question. Thanks.

If you truly need a "initialize python" function (note that changes not recorded in "a special manner" will not persist), write it in python and call it in your "autoexec.bat" (run it on eventID 7001 (Login) in Task Scheduler) or by any other means.
Otherwise:
Create your own "basic functions" for python, then do
import basicfuncs as bf
... in any python code you create, where you wish to use them.
A "def cls():" from that file would then be available to be used as bf.cls() in your subsequent code.
Example:
    $ python 
...
    >>> import primefactors as pf
    >>> pf.main(['','1234'])
    2x617
    >>> 

Where main exists as a def main(argv): in my primefactors.py,
which prints 2x617 (the actual prime factors of 1234)
when executed with the shown argument (a script or prompt-local version of the standard sys.argv).
Additionally:
import os;
os.system('');

def cls():
  print('\x1b[H\x1b[J',end='')  # Cursor Home (top left)+Clear_to_end_of_screen

The first two lines will cause WINDOWS to actually initialize something similar to ncurses (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). This will then allow all of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code where \x1b[ is equal to "CSI" i.e. \x9B in practice. CSI: Control Sequence Introducer

thanks for additionally. the others are still loading to understand it.
